Would a change in our planet's geography have saved the celtic nations from being invaded and destroyed?
So I'm writing this sort of high-fantasy ucrony in which the Romans fail to conquer the British Isles and a good portion of celtic Europe. I thought that, to make this possible, an alternate world map would be convinient; one where the area of current Galicia is much closer to the aforementioned British Isles. This could be due to either a new sea splitting the peninsula in half, or a much larger gap between the north of Africa and Spain (I haven't decided yet).
What I want to know is: Which of these alternatives would have the desired effect?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

VTC:Opinion-Based. A well-written story can rationalize either option. Questions like this are a poor fit on this Stack because you're asking us to make a story-based choice. Our sweet spot is for you to make the story-based choice and then ask us for help rationalizing it. E.G., "I've chosen X to achieve Y. Can you help me rationalize X?"

So, this is an interesting problem, but it is not well focused. "Celtic" implies a long stretch of history and an even longer stretch of geography. Literally a time span of 2500 to 3000 years and a geographical stretch from Ireland (possibly as far as Iceland) all the way down to Galicia and over to Galatia. For this query to be answerable, you'd have to nail down some times and places. And also what you mean, precisely, by "saved" in this context. Like, do you want an Ulster Cycle like kingship system to survive for a thousand years, or would medieval Scottish kingdom suffice?

The British Isles were invaded because they were believed to be rich in metal, possibly extrapolating from the tin mines of Cornwall. I am not sure that the decision to invade was logical. It probably felt safer than pushing eastwards though endless forests. Change the weather a bit. The Roman Warm Period lasted from around 250 BC to AD 400, was a time of warm, moist weather in Europe and the North Atlantic. The climate was warm enough to support vineyards in northern England. Replace that with the Little Ice Age of 1700 and they may not have bothered.
